# How do I update widgets in the window and add new widgets to the window in PyGObject?

Tags: gtk, pygobject

I have a window set up with a few widgets but I want those widgets' information to be updated after some user input (e.g. button click). Also, I want an event handler to be able to add a new widget to the window.
I have attached an attempt at the below simple version of my question. Obviously it does not work though.

```
import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gdk, Gtk

class Button(Gtk.Box):

    def __init__(self, message, label, window_grid):
        Gtk.Box.__init__(self, spacing=6)
        self.set_border_width(10)
        self.label = label
        self.window_grid = window_grid

        button = Gtk.Button.new_with_label(message)
        button.connect("clicked", self.on_click)
        self.pack_start(button, True, True, 0)

    def on_click(self, widget):
        # Change/update a label in the window_grid
        self.label = LabelBox("Changed the label")
        self.label.queue_draw()
        # Add a new label to the window_grid
        new_label = LabelBox("New label")
        self.window_grid.attach(new_label, 0, 2, 1, 1)

class LabelBox(Gtk.Box):

    def __init__(self, message):
        Gtk.Box.__init__(self, spacing=6)
        self.set_border_width(10)
        label = Gtk.Label(message)
        self.pack_start(label, True, True, 0)

win = Gtk.Window()
window_grid = Gtk.Grid()

label = LabelBox("This is a label")
button = Button("Test", label, window_grid)

window_grid.attach(label, 0, 0, 1, 1)
window_grid.attach(button, 0, 1, 2, 2)

win.add(window_grid)

win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Comment: Widgets are hidden by default.

Answer (score 0):

Your code structure is poorly formatted. This code worked for me:

```
import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk
import sys

class GUI:
    def __init__(self):

        self.win = Gtk.Window()
        self.window_grid = Gtk.Grid()
        box = Gtk.Box()

        button = Gtk.Button.new_with_label("Test")
        button.connect("clicked", self.on_click)

        self.label = Gtk.Label("This is a label")

        self.window_grid.attach(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.window_grid.attach(button, 0, 1, 2, 2)

        self.win.add(self.window_grid)

        self.win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
        self.win.show_all()

    def on_click(self, widget):
        # Change/update a label in the window_grid
        self.label.set_label('Label changed')
        label = Gtk.Label("Another label")
        self.window_grid.attach(label, 2, 1, 2, 2)
        self.win.show_all()


def main():
    app = GUI()
    Gtk.main()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

Also keep @andlabs comment in mind, widgets are hidden by default.

Comment: This is how we can add new widgets to the window, but how do we modify existing widgets (see original question)?

Comment: @Billjoe Sorry, I misunderstood your request. Try my edited code.

Comment: this works in this case with a label but I was hoping for a more general case. Suppose I have a box with some variables in it and then I change one of those variables. Now I want to update the box. How do I do that?

Comment: @Billjoe how about you explain what is not "general" about the example? What prevents you from using this approach with a box?

Comment: @jku In my actual code, I have a widget that displays a graph using graph-tool where one of the arguments is a "graph" g. At the start, my GUI has this widget display a blank graph. Then through a file_opener widget, we select a file and convert it to a new "graph". Hence g has changed. Thus how would I show the new graph (which I must compute from this new "g") in the graph widget without replacing the window entirely (deleting the old window and make a new one with this updated widget). I guess set_label seems to be a special function as it updates and displays the label also...

Comment: @Billjoe I researched graph-tool but it seems to be awkward. I cannot compile the source and no .debs to be found that work easily. I did graphing with matplotlib here a bit ago and it worked great. Would you be interested?

Answer (score 0):

As already said, your code logic ain't good. You must try to understand how to design your applications. Anyway, I've managed to get your code working to fit your question:

```
import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk

class Button(Gtk.Box):

    def __init__(self, message, label, window_grid):
        Gtk.Box.__init__(self, spacing=6)
        self.set_border_width(10)
        self.label = label
        self.window_grid = window_grid

        button = Gtk.Button.new_with_label(message)
        button.connect("clicked", self.on_click)
        self.pack_start(button, True, True, 0)

    def on_click(self, widget):
        # Change/update a label in the window_grid
        self.label.label.set_text("Changed the lable")
        # Add a new label to the window_grid
        new_label = LabelBox("New label")
        self.window_grid.attach(new_label, 0, 2, 1, 1)
        new_label.show_all()

class LabelBox(Gtk.Box):

    def __init__(self, message):
        Gtk.Box.__init__(self, spacing=6)
        self.set_border_width(10)
        self.label = Gtk.Label(message)
        self.pack_start(self.label, True, True, 0)

win = Gtk.Window()
window_grid = Gtk.Grid()

label = LabelBox("This is a label")
button = Button("Test", label, window_grid)

window_grid.attach(label, 0, 0, 1, 1)
window_grid.attach(button, 0, 1, 1, 1)

win.add(window_grid)
win.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()

Gtk.main()
```

Compare it to yours to see the mistakes you've made. There was no need to wrap the label and the button inside GtkBox.